# ¿Puedo verificar que una cadena tipo string no tenga numeros pero que si pueda tener caracteres especiales?

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python y estoy resolviendo un ejercicio que me pide verificar que la cadena ingresada por el usuario no tenga numeros pero dicha cadena debe tener caracteres como: '+' y '@'. Ya intente con isalpha(), isdigit() pero ninguna me funciona.

Comment: `if any(x.isdigit() for x in texto): print("Hay digitos")`

Comment: Estoy seguro de que no existe una función de Python que haga específicamente eso. El punto del ejercicio es que hagas esa función por ti mismo recorriendo la cadena caracter por caracter (o al menos, eso es lo que creo)

Comment: Pense en utilizar el for pero aun no hemos visto ese tema, hasta ahora estamos viendo modulos, y metodos de cadena. Gracias por tu comentario veré que puedo hacer

Comment: Entonces puedes usar un while junto a un contador en su lugar (si es que llegaron a ese tema)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.